# Is there a closed form solution to $\int_0^1 \Phi^{-1}(u)\cdot \phi(\frac{u-y}{\sigma})du$?

Tags: normal-distribution, integral

Is there a closed form solution to $\int_0^1 \Phi^{-1}(u)\cdot \phi(\frac{u-y}{\sigma})du$, where $\phi$ is the pdf of a standard normal distribution and $\Phi^{-1}$ the inverse of its cdf?

For context: I am trying to find the posterior mean for a prior $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\omega^2)$ and likelihood $y\sim\mathcal{N}(\Phi(x),\sigma^2)$.

Comment: While I have no idea what this is for, I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that this may not be the equation you're after and that you may have made a mistake getting to this point.

Comment: He could set the limits of integration as from 0 to 1.

Comment: I have reopened the question, because now we do know what you're asking, but some explanation of the origin or intended interpretation of this integral might help you, due to the possibility that some mistake might have been made.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have amended the question with the desired context!